# How CSS can disable window.onscroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem: Simple function doesn't called

```
window.onscroll = function() { 
    console.log("scroll");
}
```

It will work if I remove the CSS link from the page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/blog/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

The question:
How CSS code can disable Javascript function window.onscroll ?

The page: http://swimbi.com/blog/

The CSS : http://swimbi.com/blog/css/style.css

Comment: In other words, what CSS style should I change to make it work.

Comment: Found the solution:
1. Removed style html,body,#container { height: 100%; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually scrolling your container div.
If you do this the events fire:

```
document.getElementById("container").onscroll = function() { 
    console.log("scroll container"); 
}
```

edit: looks like something changed on the page. If you use this on the above page it works correctly:

```
jQuery("body").on("scroll", function() { 
    console.log(this) 
})
```

Comment: Just added your code to the page.
Still don't see any logs. (In Chrome)

Comment: That is weird, you sure that code is executed? I tried it by executing the code from the Chrome developer tools.

Comment: If I remove CSS link, window.onscroll executed, and I see logs.

Comment: I guess something changed, if you do this it works now: `jQuery("body").on("scroll", function() { console.log(this) })`

Comment: I found a better solution - Removed style html,body,#container { height: 100%; }
Thanks anyway.